# Evitar que se registre fecha de nacimiento con día actual

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

estoy intentando que al registrar un paciente no permita hacerlo si eligen como fecha de nacimiento el día actual o posterior al de la fecha sin embargo con el dia actual tengo problemas ya que lo uso con fecha y hora y la diferencia de segundos en el date time.now y el datetimepicker permite que se registre el usuario. me explico. uso este codigo para comprobar:

```
if (dtpfechanacimiento.Value == DateTime.Now)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("La fecha de nacimiento debe ser inferior a la fecha actual: " + DateTime.Now, "Error en la operacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               return;
            }
```

sin embargo en el debug pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver el datetime.now y el dtpfecha no tienen el mismo valor por diferencia de segundos y pasa como puedo evitar esto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías obtener la diferencia entre las fechas y verificar si ha pasado al menos un día de esta forma:

```
  if ((DateTime.Now - dtpfechanacimiento.Value).Ticks <= TimeSpan.TicksPerDay)
            {
            }
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono de maravilla

Comment: para registrar un neonato ver si ha pasado al menos 1 minuto

Answer (score 1):

> > Evitar que se registre fecha de nacimiento con día actual

El problema radica que se está comparando fecha y hora, pero en realidad debería ser solamente fecha.

Para lograrlo, debemos usar el método [ToShortDateString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.8)(esta función lo que retorna es un objeto de tipo `string`, con esto podemos comparar únicamente fechas).

```
DateTime dateCurrent = DateTime.Now;
if (dtpfechanacimiento.Value.ToShortDateString() == dateCurrent.ToShortDateString())
{
     MessageBox.Show("La fecha de nacimiento debe ser inferior a la fecha actual: " + DateTime.Now, "Error en la operacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);       
     return;
}
```

Con este código estaríamos comparando únicamente fechas, ya que cada objeto tendría solamente la fecha. Pero el problema es que este código no servirá si ingreso una fecha de nacimiento superior a la actual.

Este algoritmo me podría estar sirviendo:

- Verificamos si el año de nacimiento es mayor al año actual.
- Si la condición de arriba no se cumple, pasamos a verificar si el año de nacimiento coincide con el año actual.
- Si la condición de arriba se cumplió, pasamos a detectar si el mes ingresado es mayor al mes actual.
- Si la condición de arriba no se cumplió, pasamos a detectar si el mes ingresado coincide con el mes actual.
- Si la condición de arriba se cumplió, pasamos a verificar si el día ingresado es mayor o igual al día actual.

El algoritmo en C# quedaría de esta forma:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dateCurrent = DateTime.Now;

            //Si el año ingresado es mayor al año actual...
            if (dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Year > dateCurrent.Year)
                MessageBox.Show("La fecha de nacimiento debe ser inferior a la fecha actual: " + dateCurrent.ToShortDateString(), "Error en la operacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            //De lo contrario, si el año ingresado es igual al año actual...
            else if (dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Year == dateCurrent.Year)
            {
                //Si el mes ingresado es mayor al mes actual...
                if(dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Month > dateCurrent.Month)
                    MessageBox.Show("La fecha de nacimiento debe ser inferior a la fecha actual: " + dateCurrent.ToShortDateString(), "Error en la operacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                //Si el mes ingresado es igual al mes actual...
                else if(dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Month == dateCurrent.Month)
                {
                    //Si el día ingresado es mayor o igual al día actual...
                    if(dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Day >= dateCurrent.Day)
                        MessageBox.Show("La fecha de nacimiento debe ser inferior a la fecha actual: " + dateCurrent.ToShortDateString(), "Error en la operacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si quieres simplificar el código usando los operadores lógicos `AND` y `OR`, lo podrías hacer de esta manera:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dateCurrent = DateTime.Now;

    if( (dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Year > dateCurrent.Year) || ( (dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Year == dateCurrent.Year) && (dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Month > dateCurrent.Month || ((dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Month == dateCurrent.Month) && (dtpfechanacimiento.Value.Day >= dateCurrent.Day)))))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("La fecha de nacimiento debe ser inferior a la fecha actual: " + dateCurrent.ToShortDateString(), "Error en la operacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         return;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias lider funciona genial

Comment: @JulioAngelMejiaTejada si no hubo error, no olvides marcar la respuesta que te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Anexando a las respuestas que ya han publicado, es importante que la validación también exista en la base de datos para seguridad adicional en caso de tener alguna carga de datos por un medio distinto.

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba( FechaNacimiento datetime);

ALTER TABLE Prueba ADD CONSTRAINT CHKFechaNacimiento CHECK ( FechaNacimiento < CAST( GETDATE() AS DATE));

GO
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ( GETDATE());
GO
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ( GETDATE()-1);
GO
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ( '20191104');
GO

SELECT * FROM Prueba;

GO

DROP TABLE Prueba;
```